# Serviço de GIT lab para versionamento

Tags: git, gitlab

Instalamos o serviço do GIT LAB na Azure.

Quando executo este comando

> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin máster
> ```

mostra este erro:

> fatal: unable to access 'endereço': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

O que pode ser ?

[image: Só que está com este erro]

Answer (score 2):

O servidor git que você está tentando conectar possui um certificado auto assinado. Para desabilitar esta validação execute:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```